# how do we return sql query result data to caller function in node.js without using ajax?

Tags: mysql, node.js, return

I am new for `node.js` . I want to return data of function to caller function. please give me the ways to do it. I want to return `mysql query` result data to caller function how i do it ? thank you in advance. have a good day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013802/node-js-asynchronous-database-calls
check this thread

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return directly any result of the SQL query or any other asynchronous function. Any function that does an synchronous operation in Node.js can either take a callback or return a promise. It cannot return the result of the asynchronous operation to its caller because that result is not available yet at the point when the function returns.

For more info see those answers:

- [Return Promise result instead of Promise in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719024/return-promise-result-instead-of-promise-in-nodejs/41719314#41719314)
- [Return value in function from a promise block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785769/return-value-in-function-from-a-promise-block/40785901#40785901)
- [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success/5316805#5316805)