# Empty array is returned outside mongoose function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to take some random values from Mongo using mongoose and push it to an array.
But the array is empty outside the function:

```
exports.Run = (req, res) => {
    var response = {}
    var you = "you"
    response[you] = [];

    Model.estimatedDocumentCount().exec(function (err, count) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)

            Model.findOne()
                .skip(random)
                .exec( function (err, result) {
                    response[you].push(result);
                    console.log(response); // Array is increased each iteration
                })
        }
    })
    console.log(response); // Array is empty here
    res.status(200).send(response);
};
```

Please, how to fix that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS Asynchronous Database Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013802/node-js-asynchronous-database-calls)

Comment: @tbking It doesn't work.
I make a callback but it returns empty array. If I make another get request after the first I recieve the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it works for me:

```
exports.Run = (req, res) => {
    ex1( function(rp){
        console.log(rp);
        res.status(200).send(rp);
    });
}

function ex1(callback) {
    var response = {}
    var you = "you"
    response[you] = [];
    Model.estimatedDocumentCount().exec(async function (err, count) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
            var doc = await Model.findOne().skip(random).exec();
            response[you].push(doc);
        }
        callback(response);
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this way. Hope it should work

```
  exports.Run =async (req, res) => {
        var response = {}
        var you = "you"
        response[you] = [];
    
        var result = await Model.estimatedDocumentCount().exec(function (err, count) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
    
               await Model.findOne()
                    .skip(random)
                    .exec( function (err, result) {
                        response[you].push(result);
                        console.log(response); 
                    })
            }
    return response;
    
            })
           
    console.log(result); // Array is empty here
        res.status(200).send(result);
    };
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work :( Moreover, I get warning "Void function return value is used" at var result = await Model.estimatedDocumentCount().exec( function (err, count)